# Show that the product of complex matrices is a continuous mapping

Tags: matrices, analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $\mathbb{M}(n, \mathbb{C})$ be the space of all complex $n\times n$ matrices
>   with operatornorm. On $\mathbb{M}(n, \mathbb{C}) \times \mathbb{M}(n,
> \mathbb{C})$ we define the product metric, $d_1((A,B), (C,D)) = d(A,C)
> + d(B,C)$, with $d$ the metric on $\mathbb{M}(n, \mathbb{C})$. Show that the following mapping is continuous: $$f:\mathbb{M}(n,
> \mathbb{C}) \times \mathbb{M}(n, \mathbb{C}) \to \mathbb{M}(n,\mathbb{C}): (A,B) \mapsto AB.$$

So, to prove that $f$ is continuous in the point $(A,B)$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, I want to find a $\delta>0$, such that for all $(C,D) \in \mathbb{M}(n, \mathbb{C}) \times \mathbb{M}(n, \mathbb{C})$, if $d_1((A,B), (C,D)) < \delta$, then $d(f(A,B), f(C,D)) < \varepsilon$.

Thus $d_1((A,B),(C,D))=d(A,C) + d(B,D) = ||A-C|| + ||B-D|| < \delta$. And I want to go to $d(AB,CD) = ||AB - CD|| < \varepsilon$. Got no clue how to connect the pieces.

Is this the right approach (to me it seems this is easiest to prove, instead of showing that convergent sequences are also convergent in its image).

Comment: $$AB - CD = (A-C)D + C(B-D) + (A-C)(B-D)$$

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't see it. So then you get $||AB-CD||= || (A−C)D+C(B−D)+(A−C)(B−D) || =< ||(A-C)D|| + ||C(B−D)|| + ||(A−C)(B−D)||$ How can you get this smaller then $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Not that it matters much, but the way I've written it is better suited for $(C,D)$ being the point in which to show continuity. Anyway, I think it's easier to see if we write $(A+h)(B+k) = AB + Ak + hB + hk$. So $\lVert (A+h)(B+k) - AB\rVert \leqslant \lVert Ak\rVert + \lVert hB\rVert + \lVert hk\rVert$. Now you can make each summand small individually by imposing restirctions on the size of $h$ resp. $k$ (actually, the last is automatically made small by making the first two small, but perhaps not small enough).

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't see your point. But could I do it like this ? Let M = max(C,D). Then

$$||(A−C)D||+||C(B−D)||+||(A−C)(B−D)||<M(||A−C||+||B−D||) + ||(A−C)(B−D)|| < M \delta + \delta ^2$$

Comment: What is the maximum of two matrices? You should - if the used metric is one of the standard ones - be able to prove that $\lVert MN\rVert \leqslant \lVert M\rVert \cdot \lVert N\rVert$. Then the rest is easy.